# Correctly parse empty html tags using beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

HTML has a concept of empty elements, as listed on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/empty_element). However, beautiful soup doesn't seem to handle them properly:

```
import bs4

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(
    '<div><input name=the-input><label for=the-input>My label</label></div>',
    'html.parser'
)
print(soup.contents)
```

I get:

```
[<div><input name="the-input"><label for="the-input">My label</label></input></div>]
```

I.e. the input has wrapped the label.

**Question:** Is there any way to get beautiful soup to parse this properly? Or is there an official explanation of this behaviour somewhere I haven't found yet?

At the very least I'd expect something like:

```
[<div><input name="the-input"></input><label for="the-input">My label</label></div>]
```

I.e. the input automatically closed before the label.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in their [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) `html5lib` parses the document as the web browser does (Like `lxml`in this case). It'll try to fix your document tree by adding/closing tags when needed.

In your example I've used lxml as the parser and it gave the following result:

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(
'<div><input name=the-input><label for=the-input>My label</label></div>',
'lxml'
)
print(soup.body.contents)

[<div><input name="the-input"/><label for="the-input">My label</label></div>]
```

Note that `lxml` added html & body tags because they weren't present in the source, that is why I've printed the `body` contents.

Comment: Thanks, useful link to be aware of!

Answer (score 3):

I would say soup is doing what it can for fixing this html structure, it is actually helpful in some occasions.

Anyway, for your case I would say to use `lxml`, which will parse the html structure as you want, or maybe give a try to [`parsel`](https://github.com/scrapy/parsel)